# Method using user-defined size not returning anything to the Console

Tags: c#, methods

Below is a program that I wrote to practice some C# basics and principles.

This program asks the user for how large they want an `int` array to be, then to fill the array and finally return the average of the individual elements of the array.

I know that I can do this using LINQ but since I'm learning I need to learn the nuts and bolts way.

As it stands, the method I wrote doesn't return anything to the console, can someone give me a clue as to what's wrong with it?

There's also a comment near one of the `for` loops that I need some help understanding why it's behaving that way.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace _9_21_Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("enter the amount of numbers you would like to find the average of: ");
            int arraylength = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            int[] AverageArray = new int[arraylength];

            ////filling the array with user input
            for (int i = 0; i < AverageArray.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.Write("enter the numbers you wish to find the average for: ");
                AverageArray[i] = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            }
            //printing out the array, without the -1 the array prints out more one number than it should, don't know why
            Console.WriteLine("here is your array: ");
            for (int i = 0; i < AverageArray.Length -1 ; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(AverageArray[i]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine(Calcs.FindAverage(AverageArray));
            Console.ReadLine();


        }

    }
    //Method to find the average is another class for learning porpoises
    class Calcs
    {
        public static double FindAverage(int[] averageNumbers)
        {
            int arraySum = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < averageNumbers.Length; i++)
                arraySum += averageNumbers[i];

            return arraySum / averageNumbers.Length;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The -1 is needed because arrays are 0 based. This means an array with length (number of elements) 10, has elements 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, and 9.

Comment: So you run the program and you just get a blank, empty console with no text in it? Or did you miss that the result looks like the last number in the array, since there's no text to highlight it

Comment: The program runs fine, but the 'here is your answer' isn't returned to the console and it doesn't print out anything.

Comment: Add `Console.WriteLine("Result: ");` After writing out the array and before writing the result. The result is there it just doesn't look like it.

Comment: That does work, could you explain why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried debugging, your code is working OK. It's just you don't need the ArrayLength-1 in the second loop. Use ArrayLength instead.

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("enter array length ");
            int arraylength = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            int[] AverageArray = new int[arraylength];


            for (int i = 0; i < AverageArray.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.Write("enter the numbers you wish to find the average for: ");
                AverageArray[i] = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            }

            Console.WriteLine("here is your array: ");
            for (int i = 0; i < AverageArray.Length ; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(AverageArray[i]);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("here is the result");
            Console.WriteLine(Calcs.FindAverage(AverageArray));
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
```

Comment: When I run the program, the method doesn't return anything to the console, that's what I'm mainly after here.

Comment: Just replace your main method with this one and try again. It actually DOES print the result. You may have confused it with some other output.

Comment: Can you explain that I was doing wrong that kept mine initial shot from working?

Comment: Nothing was wrong with your code. You were not printing out the last element in the array with your -1 in the second loop. I think you were just thinking that the result (which was actually printing out after the first n-1 elements of the array) was the last element.

Answer (score 1):

Well I think Visual Studio C#(Sharp) Will give you an error on the second statement of code before the **for** loop,Because the Array uses the constant variable for the index size.

```
        Console.WriteLine("enter array length ");
  const int arraylength = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        int[] AverageArray = new int[arraylength];
```

also Check **Calcs** does not exist in the current context.